# foreach inside xdocument.add

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have a class that has a dictionary field. I want to loop through every item of this class and create an xml document but inside this loop I want to loop through this dictionary properties and add the key values pairs.

I am looking for something that will do the following

```
foreach(Book bk in query)
{
    ReturnData.Descendants("Books")
              .FirstOrDefault().Add(new XElement("Book",
                                        new XElement("Name", bk.BookName),
                                        new XElement("Measure", bk.Measure,
                                        .foreach(KeyValuePair<string, double> measure in bk.NewMeasures)
                                        {
                                            new XElement(measure.Key,measure.Value)
                                        },
                                        new XElement("Value", bk.PreviousValue))));
}
```

Return data already contains some XML, this is why I am adding to the Books descendants. It may already have other roots such as videos, games etc.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Anyone any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would query for the first *book* outside the loop:

```
var book = ReturnData.Descendants("Books").FirstOrDefault();
```

And then use it within the loop:

```
foreach(var b in query)
{
    book.Add(new XElement("Book",
                 new XElement("Name", b.Name),
                 new XElement("Measure", b.Measure,
                     from m in b.NewMeasures select new XElement(m.Key, m.Value)),
                 new XElement("Value", b.Value)));
}
```